# Magento2 Check value of attribute for IF statement

Tags: magento2, php, attributes

I am trying to check if an attribute is set to yes then show this block.

```
<?php if($_item->getAttributeText('free_shipping_toggle')=='1'): ?>      
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('free-shipping-list-marker')->toHtml();?>
<?php else: ?>
<!--Placeholder for other statement-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please add more detail which problem are you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a boolean (Yes/No) attribute, then you can use:

`if ($_item->getData('free_shipping_toggle'))`

This will check if attribute exists and if yes what values it is.